# Get pid of an running process

Tags: c++, android-studio, root

Iam trying to get the pid of an running process with packagename, iam using an c code in android studio. When i return the pid on emulator the code is giving me the true pid without problems
 but when i try on 9.0 device then iam getiing -1 as a result and i dont know what the the problem?

```
    int find_pid_of(const char *process_name)
    {
  int id;
  pid_t pid = -1;
  DIR *dir;
  FILE *fp;
  char filename[32];
  char cmdline[256];
  struct dirent *entry;
  if (process_name == NULL)
      return -1;
  dir = opendir("/proc");
  if (dir == NULL)
      return -1;
  while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
      {
         id = atoi(entry->d_name);
         if (id != 0)
            {
              sprintf(filename, "/proc/%d/cmdline", id);
              fp = fopen(filename, "r");
              if (fp)
                 {
                   fgets(cmdline, sizeof(cmdline), fp);
                   fclose(fp);
                   if (strcmp(process_name, cmdline) == 0)
                     {
                        /* process found */
                        pid = id;
                        break;
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
  closedir(dir);

}
int main(){
  pid_t pid = find_pid_of("com.anapp.ig");
    return pid;
}
```

I am also giving the root permission per java on starting the app

Comment: FYI, "ruining" is along the lines of destroying, as in "the hurricanes are ruining our levees".  The term "running", as in executing a program.  Big difference. :-)

Comment: I was trying to write runinng thx for the info